# как сделать выключение программируемой кнопки на N времени?

Tags: java, android

есть задача по нажатию кнопки выключать другие кнопки в приложении на определенное количество времени! причем что бы это все сохранялось при перезагрузке приложения! когда время закончится, то все восстанавливалось!

впринципе простой код накидал, но при перезагрузке приложения, все скидывается! заставить все это дело сохранять любые изменения?

```
serButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor exec = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
            exec.schedule(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    MapsActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                        userButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }});}}, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        }});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще, такая задача - нерешаемая, если не идти на множество компромисов.

В самом грубом приближении вам надо просто в SharedPreferences записывать отметку времени и считывать её после пересоздания активити.

Однако, т.к. отметка времени у вас будет браться из системного времени, юзер всегда может вручную это время поменять, сломав вашу логику. В этом случае вам надо отметку времени хранить на сервере, на нём же вычисляя прошло ли нужное время. Однако это потребует соединения с сетью и обработки множества случаев когда соединения нет, решая как в этом случае должно вести себя приложение.

В итоге, если вам нужно просто грубое решение с большим кол-вом недочётов - пишите и считывайте время из SharedPreferences.

Comment: что значить ваша фраза: " считывать её после пересоздания активити" ??? это типа проверять текущее время с сохрненным?

Comment: Например. Реализовать можно очень разное поведение очень разными способами по вами описанной задаче. Приведённый вами код, по идее, не будет  исполняться корректно после пересоздания активити (например после поворота экрана или смены языка девайса). В этом случае, после пересоздания активити надо бы запустить ваш код указав время срабатывания, равное `интервал - (текущее время - стартовое время)` если оно положительное. Что делать, если оно отрицательное, т.е. указанный ранее интервал времени прошёл как раз в момент пересоздания активити (или ребута девайса) - уже отдельный вопрос.

Comment: что то у меня глюки частые не понимаю почему! смотрите: мне при нажатии кнопки, надо выключать другие кнопки на время скажем (2 минуты), следовательно я записываю время обработки нажатия кнопки и после перезагрузки приложения его возвращаю, а при загрузке приложения делаю проверку на время if(2 < DiffTimeAD()) {
                button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

Comment: кароче когда работает, а когда нет! не известно почему, может надо через Handler делать с частотой обновления 10 сек ???

Comment: Если вы перезапустили приложение раньше, чем закончился интервал то да, код показа кнопок сам собой не вызовется. Надо в этом случае запускать ваш код отложенного показа кнопок, вычислив правильно время, через которое он должен сработать.

Comment: запускать ваш код отложенного показа кнопок это как?

Comment: Ну, я имел в виду тот код, что у вас в вопросе.